# Angular 2: Can't bind to x since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In Angular 2 component I have `authbox.component.ts`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {COMMON_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {Credentials} from './credentials'
@Component({
    selector: 'authbox',
    template: `<div>
       <div class="login-panel" *NgIf="!IsLogged">
            <input type="text" *NgModel="credentials.name" />
            <input type="password" *NgModel="credentials.password" />
            <button type="button" (click)="signIn(credentials)">→| Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="logged-panel" *NgIf="IsLogged">
            <span>{nickname}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" (click)="signOut()">|→ Sign out</button>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    directives: [COMMON_DIRECTIVES]
})


export class AuthBoxComponent {

    private _isLogged: boolean;

    get IsLogged(): boolean {
        return this._isLogged
    }
    set IsLogged(value: boolean) {
        this._isLogged = value;
    }

    public credentials: Credentials;

}
```

In browser I got errors «*Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known native property* » and «*Can't bind to 'NgIf' since it isn't a known native property*».

I'm using beta 8.

Comment: Same error. Maybe something with imports?

Comment: I get the feeling that you did not look at angular2 docs talking about binding syntax...
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try using `[(ngModel)]` rather than `*NgModel`  and `*ngIf` instead of `*NgIf`

```
<span>{{nickname}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" (click)="signOut()">|→ Sign out</button>

export class AuthBoxComponent {
    nickname="guest";
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI...I'm not sure but since `beta-8` it is not necessary to import `FORM_DIRECTIVES & COMMON_DIRECTIVES`

Comment: COMMON_DIRECTIVES and CORE_DIRECTIVES are or different things ?

Comment: The capitalised versions refer to the class name, the lower-case versions refer to the instances. Use the instances.

Answer (score 45):

In general, the `can't bind to xxx since it isn't a known native property` error occurs when you have a typo in your HTML when trying to use an attribute directive, or when trying to setup a property binding.

Common examples are when you miss a `*` or a `#` or `let` or use `in` instead of `of` with the Angular built-in structural directives:

```
<div  ngIf="..."                 // should be *ngIf
<div  ngFor="..."                // should be *ngFor="..."
<div *ngFor="let item in items"  // should be "let item of items"
<div *ngFor="item of items"      // should be "let item of items"
```

A misspelling or wrong case will also generate the problem::

```
<div *ngFer="..."
<div *NgFor="..."
```

Another reason is if you specify a property that doesn't exist on the DOM element or component:

```
<div [prop1]="..."       // prop1 isn't a valid DOM property for a div
<my-comp [answr]="..."   // typo, should be [answer]
```

---

For typos with the built-in Angular directives, since the typo doesn't match  any of the built-in directive selectors, Angular tries to setup a binding to a property of the DOM element (the `div` in the above examples) with the typo name.  This fails because a `div` does not have a native `ngIf` or `ngFer` or `prop1` DOM property.

--

For attributes (not properties) you need to use attribute binding, for example for `height` attribute of `svg`: `<svg [attr.height]="myHeightProp">`

Comment: Is there a way to find all native DOM properties for all elements? I'm having the same issue when I try to bind to a `height` property of an `svg` element.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such list, especially considering that, e.g., ([according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)) a DOM element inherits from Node and EventTarget, and implements  ParentNode, ChildNode, NonDocumentTypeChildNode, and Animatable.  Each of those can have their own properties.  To find properties, I normally use MDN or use Chrome dev tools (Elements, then the Properties tab).  In your case, `height` is an attribute of an svg element, not a property, so you need to use attribute binding: `<svg [attr.height]="myHeightProp">`.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute

Comment: I ran into this error because I forgot to add the directive to the directives array in the component declaration for my component.

Comment: For me, I forget to add my component in the `Exports` of my module